# I want to censor a word to asterisks based on the original length(Happy to *****, dog to *** for example) and my current code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Tags: c

Attempt at censoring "hello" to "*****" The error message it gives is signal: segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char word = "hello";
    int i;
    int len = strlen(word);
    char modified[len];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
      modified[i] = "*";
    }
    printf("%s",modified);  
}
```

Comment: Just check the warnings, this should be `char *word` for example

Comment: "Isn't working" isn't a useful problem description. Please include any errors from your compiler or errors produced by running your program.

Comment: `printf("%s"...` expects a pointer to a string. In C a string is a nul-terminated character sequence. You never provide that 0 terminator in your array. And you also don't have enough room in that array to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.

First, `char` is not a string, it's a single character, which is *essentially* a short, single byte integer. The line `char word = "hello";` takes the address of the string "hello", converts it to an integer, and assigns that integer to `word`. You don't actually want the numeric representation of the strings address, you want a pointer to the actual string, so your `word` should be a `const char*`, not a `char`.

Secondly, you don't reserve enough space for a null byte at the end of your string. Strings in C are simply sequences of characters, terminated by a null byte, and you're expected to add a null byte to your string so functions that use strings know when the string stops.

Thirdly, you're assigning the string `"*"` to each character in your `modified` array. A string is not a character, character literals are delimited with single quotes: `'*'`.

All in all, you can correct the issues and wind up with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *word = "hello";
    int i;
    int len = strlen(word);
    char modified[len + 1];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
      modified[i] = '*';
    }
    modified[len] = 0;
    printf("%s",modified);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix up char and strings `"*"` and `'*'` are very different thing in C.

Declare a const string:

```
const char* word = "hello";
```

set a char:

```
modified[i] = '*';
```

String is null terminated  => `modified[len] = '\0';`
add a `\n` to printf to have a line break

Add `return 0;`
as expected for main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char* word = "hello";
    int i;
    int len = strlen(word);
    char modified[len + 1];
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
      modified[i] = '*';
    }
    modified[len] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",modified);
    return 0;
}
```